# Where do I get a website logo if I can not describe it to a designer?

Tags: logo, designers

I need a logo for my website, and every designer wants me to participate and tell them what I want.

While I know basic concepts like sans and serif fonts, I can not visualize how it has to look like - if it was possible, I could draw it myself with some quality, but there are too many options.

Can you recommend anything?

Comment: Hi Marina, graphic designers are not magicians, what kind of recommendation do you want without even knowing what your website is about? I think you should explain a lot more, your question is too vague to elaborate an answer.

Comment: I know what my website is about, but every offer I see on the web requires more detail :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A logo is a unique and singular representation of your brand, it should be able to sum up your entire brand identity in *one single simple image*. So before making a logo for you, the designer should be able to get to know your brand identity.

So when designers ask you to tell them what you want, they are **not** asking you to describe the logo in detail. They are asking you to limit their options, by answering some fundamental (branding) questions, like:

- What is the brand/website about?
- What is the Tone of Voice of the brand/website? Do you want it to be playful or serious?
- What are  the brand colours?
- Are there things you want or do not want associated with the brand? Do you want a logo similar to your competitors/peers, or something that is noticeably different?
- Do you want the brand name in the logo or not? Should it be a unique lettertype? Or should the logo be recognisable without any text?

If you cannot answer these questions yourself, it is too early to go to a designer for a logo. First think about your brand and what you want to be about, who your target audience is, how you want to speak to them, how you want to be perceived, etc.

These are branding decisions, and while some designers might also be able to help you with that, this is more marketing-oriented and possibly a lengthy and expensive process.

In this [branding tutorial](https://www.shopify.com/blog/how-to-build-a-brand) for example, designing a logo is only step 6 of 7. And [here](https://freshsparks.com/successful-brand-building-process/) and [here](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/253750) are more great guides to building a brand.

Comment: This is really not obvious. Unfortunately I am from a location where it is assumed that "a brand is just a logo, don't waste your time and do the business". As a result, I still don't have brand identity.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what you want, then tell your graphic designer you don't know. It's perfectly OK to say you don't know.

A graphic designer's job is often to come up with ideas for clients who know nothing about graphic design, and to help them discover what it is that they actually *do* want. You don't need to imagine or draw the logo yourself, or think about fonts, or other specifics.

However, your graphic designer will still need you to participate and communicate, and will still need to ask questions about your business, your products, your clients, the market you sell to, etc.  This will help your designer to come up with logo ideas suited to your business needs.

You may still have to make choices about the final design, but you can allow yourself to be guided by your designer. When stumped by a choice, it's also perfectly OK to ask your graphic designer for their opinion/recommendation.